# TActionMainMenuBar overflow with items more than screen space is causing random submenu to auto clicked

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I saw in case of screen overflow if there are more sub-menu items seems like while clicking the parent menu **.vcl** code adds the subitems in the selected list and fires the execute for that as it's treating this mouse click for the child menu too.
any solution for this or its a bug in .vcl?
Display setting: scale (125%) display resolution (1920 * 1080)

**.dfm file**

```
object frmCodeTree: TfrmCodeTree
  Left = 353
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'CodeTree'
  ClientHeight = 598
  ClientWidth = 1101
  Color = clBtnFace
  CustomTitleBar.Control = TitleBarPanel1
  CustomTitleBar.Enabled = True
  CustomTitleBar.Height = 58
  CustomTitleBar.SystemHeight = False
  CustomTitleBar.SystemColors = False
  CustomTitleBar.SystemButtons = False
  CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor = clGreen
  CustomTitleBar.ForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = clGreen
  CustomTitleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = clGreen
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = clGreen
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = clGreen
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = clWhite
  CustomTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = clGreen
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIForm
  GlassFrame.Enabled = True
  GlassFrame.Top = 58
  OldCreateOrder = True
  Position = poDesigned
  ShowHint = True
  StyleElements = [seFont, seClient]
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 1101
    Height = 57
    CustomButtons = <>
    object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
      Left = 408
      Top = 3
      Width = 329
      Height = 41
      HorzScrollBar.ButtonSize = 11
      VertScrollBar.ButtonSize = 11
      VertScrollBar.Position = 8
      TabOrder = 0
      object ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar
        Left = 0
        Top = -8
        Width = 308
        Height = 50
        UseSystemFont = False
        ActionManager = ActionManager1
        Align = alBottom
        AllowHiding = True
        Caption = 'ActionMainMenuBar1'
        Color = clMenuBar
        ColorMap.DisabledFontColor = 7171437
        ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
        ColorMap.BtnSelectedFont = clBlack
        ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
        Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        Font.Color = clBlack
        Font.Height = -12
        Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
        Font.Style = []
        Spacing = 0
        OnGetPopupClass = ActionMainMenuBar1GetPopupClass
        OnPaint = ActionMainMenuBar1Paint
      end
    end
  end
  object ActionManager1: TActionManager
    ActionBars = <
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = FileOpen1
                ImageIndex = 7
                ShortCut = 16463
              end
              item
                Action = FileOpenWith1
                Caption = 'O&pen with...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileSaveAs1
                ImageIndex = 30
              end
              item
                Action = FilePrintSetup1
              end
              item
                Action = FilePageSetup1
                Caption = 'Pa&ge Setup...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileRun1
              end
              item
                Action = FileExit1
                ImageIndex = 43
              end
              item
                Action = BrowseForFolder1
                Caption = '&BrowseForFolder1'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem8'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'A&ctionClientItem9'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'Ac&tionClientItem10'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'Act&ionClientItem11'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem12'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'Actio&nClientItem13'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionC&lientItem14'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionCli&entItem15'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientIte&m16'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem&17'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem1&8'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem1&9'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem&20'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem21'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem22'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem2&3'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem2&4'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem2&5'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem2&6'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem2&7'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem28'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem29'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem3&0'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem31'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem32'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem33'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem34'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem35'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem36'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem37'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem38'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem39'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem40'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem41'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem42'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem43'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem44'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem45'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem46'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem47'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem48'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem49'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem50'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem51'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem52'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem53'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem54'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem55'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem56'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem57'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem58'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem59'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem60'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem61'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem62'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem63'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem64'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem65'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem66'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem67'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem68'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem69'
              end
              item
                Caption = 'ActionClientItem70'
              end>
            Tag = 777
            Caption = '&File'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = EditUndo1
                ImageIndex = 3
                ShortCut = 16474
              end
              item
                Action = EditDelete1
                ImageIndex = 5
                ShortCut = 46
              end>
            Caption = '&Edit'
          end
          item
            Caption = '&View'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = SearchFindFirst1
              end>
            Caption = '&Repository'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = InternetBrowseURL1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetDownLoadURL1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetSendMail1
              end>
            Caption = '&Actions'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action1
                Caption = '&Options'
              end>
            Caption = '&Tools'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action2
                Caption = '&About CodeTree'
              end>
            Caption = '&Help'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = SearchFindFirst1
              end>
            Caption = 'Re&pository'
          end
          item
            Caption = 'V&iew'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = FileOpen1
                ImageIndex = 7
                ShortCut = 16463
              end
              item
                Action = FileOpenWith1
                Caption = 'O&pen with...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileSaveAs1
                ImageIndex = 30
              end
              item
                Action = FilePrintSetup1
              end
              item
                Action = FilePageSetup1
                Caption = 'Pa&ge Setup...'
              end
              item
                Action = FileRun1
              end
              item
                Action = FileExit1
                ImageIndex = 43
              end
              item
                Action = BrowseForFolder1
                Caption = '&BrowseForFolder1'
              end
              item
                Items = <
                  item
                    Action = SearchFindFirst1
                  end>
                Caption = 'R&epository'
                UsageCount = 1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetBrowseURL1
                Caption = 'Bro&wse URL'
              end
              item
                Action = InternetDownLoadURL1
              end
              item
                Action = InternetSendMail1
              end
              item
                Action = Action2
                Caption = 'Abou&t CodeTree'
              end
              item
                Action = Action3
                Caption = 'A&ction3'
              end
              item
                Action = Action4
                Caption = 'Act&ion4'
              end
              item
                Action = Action5
                Caption = 'Actio&n5'
              end
              item
                Action = Action6
                Caption = 'Action&6'
              end
              item
                Action = Action7
                Caption = 'Action&7'
              end
              item
                Action = Action8
                Caption = 'Action&8'
              end
              item
                Action = Action9
                Caption = 'Action&9'
              end
              item
                Action = Action10
                Caption = 'Action&10'
              end
              item
                Action = Action11
              end
              item
                Action = Action12
                Caption = 'Action1&2'
              end
              item
                Action = Action13
                Caption = 'Action1&3'
              end
              item
                Action = Action14
                Caption = 'Action1&4'
              end
              item
                Action = Action15
                Caption = 'Action1&5'
              end
              item
                Action = Action16
              end
              item
                Action = Action17
              end
              item
                Action = Action18
              end
              item
                Action = Action19
              end
              item
                Action = Action20
                Caption = 'Action2&0'
              end
              item
                Action = Action21
              end
              item
                Action = Action22
              end
              item
                Action = Action23
              end
              item
                Action = Action24
              end
              item
                Action = Action25
              end
              item
                Action = Action26
              end
              item
                Action = Action27
              end
              item
                Action = Action28
              end
              item
                Action = Action29
              end
              item
                Action = Action34
              end>
            Caption = 'A&ctions'
          end>
        ActionBar = ActionMainMenuBar1
      end>
    Left = 600
    Top = 278
    StyleName = 'Platform Default'
    object EditUndo1: TEditUndo
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Undo'
      Hint = 'Undo|Reverts the last action'
      ImageIndex = 3
      ShortCut = 16474
    end
    object EditDelete1: TEditDelete
      Category = 'Edit'
      Caption = '&Delete'
      Hint = 'Delete|Erases the selection'
      ImageIndex = 5
      ShortCut = 46
    end
    object FileOpen1: TFileOpen
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Open...'
      Hint = 'Open|Opens an existing file'
      ImageIndex = 7
      ShortCut = 16463
    end
    object FileOpenWith1: TFileOpenWith
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Open with...'
      FileName = ''
    end
    object FileSaveAs1: TFileSaveAs
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Save &As...'
      Hint = 'Save As|Saves the active file with a new name'
      ImageIndex = 30
    end
    object FilePrintSetup1: TFilePrintSetup
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Print Set&up...'
      Hint = 'Print Setup'
    end
    object FilePageSetup1: TFilePageSetup
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Page Set&up...'
      Dialog.MinMarginLeft = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginTop = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginRight = 0
      Dialog.MinMarginBottom = 0
      Dialog.MarginLeft = 1000
      Dialog.MarginTop = 1000
      Dialog.MarginRight = 1000
      Dialog.MarginBottom = 1000
      Dialog.PageWidth = 8500
      Dialog.PageHeight = 11000
    end
    object FileRun1: TFileRun
      Category = 'Actions'
      Browse = False
      BrowseDlg.Title = 'Run'
      Caption = '&Run...'
      Hint = 'Run|Runs an application'
      Operation = 'open'
      ShowCmd = scShowNormal
    end
    object FileExit1: TFileExit
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'E&xit'
      Hint = 'Exit|Quits the application'
      ImageIndex = 43
    end
    object BrowseForFolder1: TBrowseForFolder
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'BrowseForFolder1'
      DialogCaption = 'BrowseForFolder1'
      BrowseOptions = []
      BrowseOptionsEx = []
    end
    object InternetBrowseURL1: TBrowseURL
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Browse URL'
      Hint = 'Browse URL'
    end
    object InternetDownLoadURL1: TDownLoadURL
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Download URL'
      Hint = 'Download from URL'
    end
    object InternetSendMail1: TSendMail
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = '&Send Mail...'
      Hint = 'Send email'
    end
    object SearchFindFirst1: TSearchFindFirst
      Category = 'Repository'
      Caption = 'F&ind First'
      Hint = 'Find First|Finds the first occurance of specified text'
    end
    object Action1: TAction
      Category = 'Tools'
      Caption = 'Options'
    end
    object Action2: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'About CodeTree'
    end
    object Action3: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action3'
    end
    object Action4: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action4'
    end
    object Action5: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action5'
    end
    object Action6: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action6'
    end
    object Action7: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action7'
    end
    object Action8: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action8'
    end
    object Action9: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action9'
    end
    object Action10: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action10'
    end
    object Action11: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action11'
    end
    object Action12: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action12'
    end
    object Action13: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action13'
    end
    object Action14: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action14'
    end
    object Action15: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action15'
    end
    object Action16: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action16'
    end
    object Action17: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action17'
    end
    object Action18: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action18'
    end
    object Action19: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action19'
    end
    object Action20: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action20'
    end
    object Action21: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action21'
    end
    object Action22: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action22'
    end
    object Action23: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action23'
    end
    object Action24: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action24'
    end
    object Action25: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action25'
    end
    object Action26: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action26'
    end
    object Action27: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action27'
    end
    object Action28: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action28'
    end
    object Action29: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action29'
    end
    object Action34: TAction
      Category = 'Actions'
      Caption = 'Action34'
    end
  end
end
```

**my .pas file**

```
unit CodeTreeForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  System.Actions,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.TitleBarCtrls,
  Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.StdActns,
  Vcl.ExtActns,
  Vcl.ActnList,
  Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnMan,
  Vcl.ToolWin,
  Vcl.ActnCtrls,
  Vcl.ActnMenus,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
   Vcl.ThemedActnCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TMyThemedPopupMenu = class(TThemedPopupMenu)
  protected
    procedure PositionPopup(AnOwner: TCustomActionBar; ParentItem: TCustomActionControl); override;


  end;

type
  TfrmCodeTree = class(TForm)
    TitleBarPanel1: TTitleBarPanel;
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    EditUndo1: TEditUndo;
    EditDelete1: TEditDelete;
    FileOpen1: TFileOpen;
    FileOpenWith1: TFileOpenWith;
    FileSaveAs1: TFileSaveAs;
    FilePrintSetup1: TFilePrintSetup;
    FilePageSetup1: TFilePageSetup;
    FileRun1: TFileRun;
    FileExit1: TFileExit;
    BrowseForFolder1: TBrowseForFolder;
    InternetBrowseURL1: TBrowseURL;
    InternetDownLoadURL1: TDownLoadURL;
    InternetSendMail1: TSendMail;
    SearchFindFirst1: TSearchFindFirst;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Action3: TAction;
    Action4: TAction;
    Action5: TAction;
    Action6: TAction;
    Action7: TAction;
    Action8: TAction;
    Action9: TAction;
    Action10: TAction;
    Action11: TAction;
    Action12: TAction;
    Action13: TAction;
    Action14: TAction;
    Action15: TAction;
    Action16: TAction;
    Action17: TAction;
    Action18: TAction;
    Action19: TAction;
    Action20: TAction;
    Action21: TAction;
    Action22: TAction;
    Action23: TAction;
    Action24: TAction;
    Action25: TAction;
    Action26: TAction;
    Action27: TAction;
    Action28: TAction;
    Action29: TAction;
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar;
    Action34: TAction;
    procedure pgcRepositoriesMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ActionMainMenuBar1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ActionMainMenuBar1GetPopupClass(Sender: TObject;
      var PopupClass: TCustomPopupClass);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  frmCodeTree: TfrmCodeTree;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TfrmCodeTree.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 ;//PostMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TfrmCodeTree.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
//var
// ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
begin
  // The ActionMainMenuBar does not draw correctly in the title bar area. So DoubleBuffered must be enabled, and
  // Transparent must be set to False

  ScrollBox1.Parent := TitleBarPanel1;

  ActionMainMenuBar1.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Align := altop;


  ActionMainMenuBar1.DoubleBuffered := True;
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Transparent := False;


  ActionManager1.ActionBars[0].Items[0].Tag := 777;
end;


procedure TMyThemedPopupMenu.PositionPopup(AnOwner: TCustomActionBar; ParentItem: TCustomActionControl);
var
  ParentItemPosition: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
            var tag := TActionClientItem(ParentItem).Tag ;
  if Assigned(AnOwner) and (AnOwner.Align = alBottom) and
  (ParentItem.Caption = frmCodeTree.ActionManager1.ActionBars[0].Items[0].Caption) and
     Assigned(ParentItem) and (ParentItem is TCustomMenuButton) then
  begin
   // ParentItemPosition := ParentItem.ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
    //if (ParentItemPosition.Y < Top) and (0 <= Top - Height - ParentItem.Height) then

       tag := TContainedAction(ParentItem).Tag ;
      Left :=ParentItem.Width + Left  ;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmCodeTree.ActionMainMenuBar1GetPopupClass(Sender: TObject;
  var PopupClass: TCustomPopupClass);
begin
if PopupClass = TThemedPopupMenu then
    PopupClass := TMyThemedPopupMenu;

end;

procedure TfrmCodeTree.ActionMainMenuBar1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Paint the background of the ActionMainMenuBar. Please note that for this app, the title bar is always the
  // same color regardless of whether or not the app is active or inactive.
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Canvas.Brush.Color := CustomTitleBar.BackgroundColor;
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Canvas.FillRect( ActionMainMenuBar1.ClientRect );
end;


procedure TfrmCodeTree.pgcRepositoriesMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  sc_DragMove = $F012;
begin
  // This event handler allows the user to drag the form around when clicking on the background area of the tab control
  ReleaseCapture;
  Perform( wm_SysCommand, sc_DragMove, 0 );
end;

 end.
```